# Obtaining RGB color from UIButton (UIColor) backgroundColor in Swift

Tags: swift, optimization, uibutton, background-color

I have three `UIButtons` and each has a different (UIColor) `backgroundColor`; for example, the `backgroundColor` of one `UIButton` is blue, one is pink, the other is orange. When I click each `UIButton`, I want to obtain the exact RGB (Red, Green, Blue) color values directly from it's `backgroundColor` property. (For example, if I clicked the `UIButton` with the pink `backgroundColor`, I will get a returned RGB values- R: 255, G: 0, B: 128.) Another way to explain this is, I want to convert a `UIButton`'s UIColor `backgroundColor` into UIColor RGB values.

In Swift, what is the most simple, most efficient code to extract the RGB (Red, Green, Blue) color values of a `UIButton`'s `backgroundColor` and then display the result in a `UILabel`?

[image: My buttons]

Comment: Why? Your model should inform you of the value you need, not the view.

Comment: @Wain Thanks for your reply. Interesting you mention this. Why is the model better to inform the value instead of the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your task consists of three parts:

- Obtaining the button that has been clicked from the click event handler
- Given a `UIButton` obtain its background color, and
- Given a `UIColor` obtain its RGB components

The first task is simple: add `sender` to the method that processes the click. The second task is also straightforward - all you need to do is accessing `backgroundColor` property. Finally, to get the components you need to call `getRGB`.

```
@IBAction func mainButton(button: UIButton) {
    let bgColor:UIColor = button.backgroundColor!
    var r : CGFloat = 0
    var g : CGFloat = 0
    var b : CGFloat = 0
    var a: CGFloat = 0
    if bgColor.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a) {
        ... r, g, b, and a represent the component values.
    } 
}
```

Note that it would be much simpler to do this the MVC way, i.e. by retrieving the components pre-stored in the model. Set your button tags to 0, 1, and 2, make a look-up table, and use it to perform the task:

```
let componentForTag: Int[][] = [[255, 0, 128], [128, 0, 0],[128, 128, 0]]
...
@IBAction func mainButton(button: UIButton) {
    let components = componentForTag[button.tag]
    // That's it! components array has the three components
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. The line `UIColor bgColor = button.backgroundColor!` wasn’t working in Swift 2 so I changed it to `let bgColor: UIColor = button.backgroundColor!` and the first option worked very well. I was aware of a lookup table in the second method, and this is a good solution if things remain mostly static with a few buttons, but I like the ability of the first method to choose the color ‘on the go’ direct from the source. I wasn’t aware of `getRed` and see there is `getHue` and `getWhite` I will investigate these in more detail. Appreciate your response and help. Cheers